# Does .NET have a way of resolving a null string to String.Empty?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a one line method that resolves a null string to string.Empty which I thought might be useful as an extension method - but I can't find a useful way of making it so.

The only way I could see it being useful is as a static method on the string class because obviously it can't be attributed to an instance as the instance is null and this causes a compiler error. [Edit: Compiler error was due to uninitialized variable, which I misinterpreted]

I thought about adding it to a helper class but that just adds unnecessary complexity from a discoverability standpoint.

So this question is in two parts I suppose:

1. Does the .NET framework have a built in way of resolving a null string to string.Empty that is common knowledge that I have missed somewhere along the way?
2. If it doesn't - does anyone know of a way to add this method as a static extension of the string class?

Cheers in advance

Edit:

Okay, I guess I should've been a little more clear - I'm already well aware of null coallescing and I was using this in a place where I've got a dozen or so strings being inspected for calculation of a hash code.

As you can imagine, 12 lines of code closely following each other all containing the null coallescing syntax is an eyesore, so I moved the null coallescing operation out to a method to make things easier easier on the eyes.  Which is perfect, however, it would be a perfect extension to the string object:

```
int hashcode =
FirstValue.ResolveNull().GetHashCode() ^
SecondValue.ResolveNull().GetHashCode() ^
...
```

over a dozen lines is a lot easier to read than:

```
int hashcode =
(FirstValue ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^
(SecondValue ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^
...
```

I was running into compiler problems when I didn't explicitly declare my string values as null but relied on the implicit:

```
 string s;
```

If however, you explicitly define:

```
string s = null;
```

You can quite easily call:

```
s.ResolveNull();
```

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Based on the 6 replies within 30 seconds, yep, common knowledge. :D

Comment: lol - it wasn't that I missed null coallescing either, I knew that, had already written it off as ugly for this particular purpose.  I guess I should've been more specific with my question :D

Comment: I think code that cant handle a null string is ugly :-P

Comment: @Allen LOL - tell that to string.GetHashCode(), I didn't write it ;)

Comment: Who ever said that Microsoft never writes ugly code? :)

Comment: `String.GetHashCode` cannot "handle" null because it is an instance method, and instance methods (in C#, anyway) are not supposed to be called with `null` receivers in general.

Comment: @Allen I'll stay out of that debate :P

Comment: @Pavel yes, that is understandable a object that is null technically doesn't have any methods - as there's nothing there to have methods on.  What I missed was that you can run extension methods on a null receiver which makes things a lot prettier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The only way I could see it being useful is as a static method on the string class because obviously it can't be attributed to an instance as the instance is null and this would cause a runtime error.

C# 3.0 extension methods can be called on null receivers (since they are static in practice), but behave as instance methods. So just make it an extension method.

Comment: Your point on being able to call extension methods on null is 100% correct (+1) - but it will usually be more effort than null-coalescing.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that coming - you're right.  I'd not actually assigned null to my string, it was just defaulting to null after instantiation so I was getting a compiler error.  When I actually declared string s = null; it fixed the issue - even though the value was still null... odd

Comment: I agree, Marc - which is why I actually voted for the first answer that mentioned `??` (Matt's). This was just to point out the incorrect statement in the question.

Comment: Ben, local variables don't "default to null". They "default" to being uninitialized, and therefore the compiler will complain when you try to do anything with such a variable short of assigning a value it (or passing it as an `out` parameter, letting someone else do that). This has absolutely nothing to do with `null`. Try it with `int` or any other value type (which cannot be `null`) and see how it works there.

Comment: Don't need to resolve null on those as they've got default values int is 0 for instance - I was only having the problem with my string values.

Comment: Local variables _do not have default_ values. Local ints _do not_ default to 0. Try `int x; Console.WriteLine(x);` and see. I assume you're talking about locals here because you mentioned that you mentioned earlier that you were "getting a compiler error" - there's no way you can get a compiler error about `null`, but you can and will get one for uninitialized locals.

Comment: @Pavel: okay, I need more sleep - I just had to read that 3 times before it made sense, lol - yes, you're right.  My test code is using locals, my application code is using fields - hence the discrepancy.

Answer (score 25):

I don't think there's anything built in for this. My first thought, and what I do often, is use the coalesce operator:

```
string s = null;
string x = s ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Idk why anyone would do this when they can just add string.Empty

Comment: @Allen - semantically, this makes it perfectly clear that the user wants an empty string instead of null. If you're adding empty strings to what appears to be an existing string, someone may misinterpret what exactly that code is supposed to be doing

Comment: *shrugs* I showed the IL in my post and they are the same so its up to style, IMO, my solution reads clearer but thats subjective

Comment: Looks ugly as hell if you've got many lines all needing to be resolved though, which is why I wanted to put it into an extension method.

Comment: You can write it as `(s ?? "")` as well, which is likely to be shorter than any extension method :)

Comment: Being short and being readable aren't necessarily the same thing.  When you've got a dozen lines all on top of each other that are full of symbols, like question marks, quote marks and parenthesis it's easy to start looking ugly fast.

Answer (score 4):

someExpressionInvolving(s ?? "");

There is no point getting excited about `string.Empty` vs `""` - there is negligible difference:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(string.Empty, "")); // true
```

Comment: My static method uses a null coallescing - I was just trying to make things more readable as I have a dozen lines checking different fields and it looks ugly as sin.

Answer (score 3):

Extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static String EmptyIfNull(this String instance)
    {
        return instance ?? String.Empty;
    }
}
```

of course, you can just as easily write `instance ?? String.Empty` in places where you need to use String.Empty instead of null.

Comment: I was using it in place where I'm calculating a hashcode, alas I have a dozen string fields that could be null and it looks ugly as all hell.  I thought it would look prettier as a static extension method on string - i.e. string.ResolveNull(stringValue).GetHashCode()

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = CouldReturnNull() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [?? Operator (null-coalescing operator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in C# - is that what you mean? Or have I misunderstood?

eg.

```
string n = null;
string y = n ?? String.Empty;
```

y would = String.Empty;

Answer (score 1):

```
string abc = s ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add string.Empty** to any string variable and you'll be guaranteed to never get null

```
string a = null;
string b = null + string.Empty;
string c = "a" + string.Empty;

(a == string.Empty).Dump(); // False
(b == string.Empty).Dump(); // True
(c == "a").Dump(); // True
```

I threw this in LinqPad, hence the .Dump()'s

**Looking at your options...**

This technique

```
string b = null + string.Empty;
```

generates

```
IL_0001:  ldsfld      System.String.Empty
IL_0006:  dup         
IL_0007:  brtrue.s    IL_000F
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ldstr       ""
IL_000F:  stloc.0
```

The other popular option:

```
string b = null ?? string.empty
```

generates

```
IL_0001:  ldsfld      System.String.Empty
IL_0006:  stloc.0
```

and this

```
string b = null + "";
```

generates this

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       ""
IL_0006:  stloc.0
```

I still favor

```
string b = null + "";
```

But really, IMO, you should just be prepared to handle null when you digest the string

Answer (score 0):

I would say that implementing this as an extension method would feel a bit like what we in Sweden call *"to travel to the other side of the creek to fetch water"*. When I need to ensure I get an empty string instead of null I often just concatenate with `string.Empty`:

```
public void SomeMethod(string param)
{
    string notNull = param + string.Empty;
}
```

Sure, this may lead to an extra string instance being created, but in most real-world situations I have been in this has not been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in function for that. But you can write a little extension method (or a static menthod) for the string type with a statement like:

return s ?? string.Emtpy;

Comment: its a bit much work, because he's talking about assigning, not inspecting.  But typically yeah I try to use that